# Overloading istream operator

Tags: c++, string, istream

I have a String class. I want to overload operator >>. Found the following way, but as far as I understand, the zero character is not added at the end (line terminator). How can I write a good operator >>?

```
class String {
 public:
  char* str;
  size_t size;
  size_t capacity;

  ~String();
  String(const char*);
  friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream&, String&);
};

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, String& obj) {
      is.read(obj.str, obj.size);
      return is;
    }
```

Comment: You can terminate your string with `obj.str[obj.size] = '\0';` ...  however you have a more fundamental issue here, which is that your design requires that you allocate a string of exactly the right length _before_ reading it from the stream.  That is not how string input from streams works.

Comment: @paddy That is, I need to write a separate function outside the class for the implementation? I don’t understand how to act for me. I did obj.str [obj.size] = '\ 0' too but I get errors from Valgrind. segmentation fault (core dumped)

Comment: If you are trying to emulate standard string input, you need to read characters one at a time until you determine that the string is complete.  That is, when you encounter any whitespace character.  Each time you read a character, you need to append that to your string and that means you also need to grow the string buffer if the capacity is not sufficient.  After you are done, you write a final string terminator (if your class requires it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start with the obvious part: your `operator>>` needs to actually create a valid `String` object based on the input you read. Let's assume you're going  to read an entire line of input as your string (stopping at a new-line, or some maximum number of characters).

For the moment, I'm going to assume that the `str` member of any `String` is either a null pointer, or a pointer to data that's been allocated with `new`.

```cpp
std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &is, String &obj) { 
    static char buffer[max_size];

    is.getline(buffer, max_size);
    std::size_t size = std::strlen(buffer);
    if (size > 0) {
        if (size > obj.size) {
            delete [] obj.str;
            obj.str = new char [size+1];
            obj.capacity = size;
        }
        strcpy(obj.str, buffer);
        obj.size = size;
    }
    return is;
}
```

That isn't intended to handle every corner case (e.g., it has no error handling), but at least gives sort of the general idea--you'll need to read in the text, check that you have enough space to store the text, allocate more if needed, copy the text into the (existing or newly allocated) space, and update at least the size to the current size, and if you reallocated, the capacity to the updated capacity as well.

Comment: It should just use the existing `const char*` constructor once it reads the buffer from the file.